# Covariance when exponentiating a normal random variable

Tags: probability

Say $Z \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$.  I am trying to figure out what is the variance of $Y = exp(Z)$.

The first thing that came to mind was approximate $exp(Z)$ with a second order taylor series, then it boils down to finding the variance of a polynomial.  But then what is the covariance term of $(Z, Z^2)$?

Comment: What is $Z$? Do you mean $X$? If yes, then use moment generating function of $X$ i.e. $M_X(t)=E(e^{tX})=e^{t\mu+t^2/2\sigma^2}.$

Comment: More answers can be found by searching our site for [lognormal moments](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=lognormal+moments).

Comment: Finding the covariance of $(Z,Z^2)$ does not require introducing $Y=\exp(Z),$ which seems superfluous for that purpose.  Are you trying to ask a question about lognormal moments (moments of $Y$), about covariances of polynomials in a *normal* variable (such as $Z$ and $Z^2$), or something else?